# How do I properly start libgdx game from activity and pass data to it?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, libgdx

I want to pass some credentials data after user 'log in'/'sign in' from my android application to libgdx game.

Firsly I want to ask you - is it good practice to just start my game using the intent?

I have declared my start activity in manifest.xml file as .LoginActivity (for example), and then after user do some action - android side is starting the game using next code:

```
private void initializeListeners(){

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AndroidLauncher.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Is there some best practices how do I start my game from activity ?

Another question related is - how do I pass data from android acitivity to libgdx game?

I saw some suggestions at this link: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code .

I am not using Swarm framework yet(maybe later) and I want to use my own interfaces to pass the data in to the game.

I have declared next interface:

```
public interface DataPasser {
    void passData(String userName);
}
```

And implement it inside Screen implementation inside core part of the game, smth like this:

```
@Override
    public void passData(String userName) {
        font.draw(batch, userName, 0, 450);
    }
```

I just draw a string with passed data.

The main problem is - when should I call this method inside my android part?

I am calling the Intent and game is starting without passed data inside the intent - that's why I asking - what's the best way to start the game.

How should I pass the data  and start the game - suggest something please.

Answer (score 2):

you didn't have much code, so a lot of this is general tips.

In the core module you add a constructor with the arguments you want (the LibGDX game itself, assuming you used the project generator).

You add a constructor where you take in two strings: username and password.

You use Intent to pass the data from one activity to the game activity, and the game activity sends the Strings to the constructor of the game.

Comment: Basically, you can pass the STrings to the game itself (probably in the core module). You don't need to use interfaces or any classes for that matter, you can just send the data directly and draw it irrelevant ov where it comes from

Comment: yeah thanks for the suggestions. I have tryed the first one and it helped me out. But still it looks a bit ugly, because I should pass data all the way to destination class (that implementing screen to draw user name) using the constructor or some set method. But I am new in libgdx - maybe It's wrong that I am using StpriteBatch object from parent class to draw something in child class using it.

Comment: It just seems easier IMO to pass the data directly to the class than have to deal with interfaces and classes. You can still use the constructor, any projects you have call the constructor in the core module

Answer (score 0):

write your android activity here and pass userName in constructor.

```
class AndroidLauncher : AndroidApplication() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()
    //pass your name here
    mainClass = ApplicationCore("username");
    initialize(mainClass, config);
}

/*
* all stuff code
*/
}
```

this is your core mainClass.

```
public class ApplicationCore extends ApplicationAdapter {
public String userName;

public ApplicationCore(String userName) {
    this.userName=userName;
// use this username whenever you want.
}

@Override
public void create() {
    initGame();
}

private void initGame() {
  //write code for initialize
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //render functionalities 
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    super.resume();

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    super.pause();
}
}
```